# Changing the color of elements in a React Form when loading

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to show a react form, styled with a color passed to it through a prop in a function.

Getting the color passed is not a problem.

Somewhere, I need to apply this color to the style of some elements of the form.

```
  document.getElementById("loginanchorlink").style.color = ctaColor;
  document.getElementById("loginsubmitbutton").style.backgroundColor = ctaColor;
  document.getElementById("loginsubmitbutton").style.borderColor = ctaColor;
  document.getElementById("loginanchorforgot").style.color = ctaColor;
```

I have tried the **useEffect** and **useLayoutEffect** hooks to do this, even a **timer**,  but the style property is not rendered yet and returns a null.

Maybe i am going about doing it the wrong way?

I'm new @this so plse be kind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the loginanchorlink and loginsubmitbutton (and so on) in your JSX, you can pass in either a CSS class name or a style parameter with CSS (see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/8-ways-to-style-react-components/).

If you reference the color property you mentioned as part of the CSS style object you pass in, then it should update when the prop updates.